# Seam EntityQuery without Transactions?

Tags: exception, jpa, view, transactions, seam

I'm using the code found [here](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/tutorial/codeless-ajax-ordered-and-paginated-tables-in-seam/) for Ajax ordered/pagination support for a Seam EntityQuery.  The code itself is working great, and I am able to sort my data with no problem by various parameters.  The entity itself is not a SQL table, but rather a SQL view mapped to a JPA (Hibernate) Entity.  That, too, seems to be working without issue, so long as I stick to SELECT statements and not try to perform an INSERT or UPDATE.  My backend DB is PostgreSQL 8.4, and I haven't implemented any conditional TRIGGERs to allow for VIEW update support.

My problem has to do when I go from one page of results to another using the EntityQuery.next() or EntityQuery.previous() methods.  It appears the entire page request is wrapped in a transaction, and when I click my next button it attempts to perform an UPDATE on my Entity object.  I've overridden the next() method in my EntityQuery and that operation goes through successfully.  But, immediately after it finishes and right before the view is rendered the attempted UPDATE occurs.  Since my Entity object can't be updated on the backend DB (since it's a VIEW) I get an Exception thrown.

Is there any way to prevent a transaction from being opened when using this EntityQuery?  I've tried annotating my Entity object with @ReadOnly.  That didn't work.  I've tried adding @Transactional(NEVER) to my EntityQuery.  That didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to session scope on your component. That way seam will load the object from memory instead of hitting the database.

```
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
```